# Importing $\LaTeX$

Tags: import, latex

I have a *LaTex* file, and import it this way:

```
tex=Import["texfile.tex"];
```

Now according to *Help*, this returns a notebook expression:

```
Notebook[{Cell[
   TextData[{"Question  Define the potential temperature ", 
     Cell[BoxData[FormBox["\[Theta]", TraditionalForm]], 
      "InlineFormula"], ". "}], "Section"]}, 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Article/LaTeX-Article.nb"]
```

But what do I do with that?  I want it displayed as text.  *Help* refers to [`Notebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Notebook.html) but that is of no help really.

Comment: You can use it with `CreateDocument`, or you can pick it to parts and do something with the cells separately.

Comment: Isn't there some simple way to convert it to text, like Print[tex]? I do not want to write tons of code just to import latex, it would be almost faster to rewrite it then. Also I want to use it for part of a document (imagine first part is more easier to write in Latex the other in Mathematica (as it contains some calculations as well) so CreateDocument probably is not the best option.

Comment: Have you tried `CreateDocument`?  I do not understand your comment.  It will give you the text in a readable, copyable, editable form.

Answer (score 7):

```
NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], Import["ExampleData/test.tex"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]